# How do I upgrade from Ubuntu 16.04 to the latest?

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, chromeos

After trying to add the repositories for 16.10 it doesn't even show up in the sources. After running terminal for the upgrade it stated:

```
org.freedesktop.PolicyKit.Error.Failed: ('system-bus-name', {'name': ':1.87'}): org.debian.apt.update-cache
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to type sudo apt-get dist-upgrade it will ask you for your password then you can proceed to the upgrade. Make sure you have the repositories for 17.04 Zesty so you can upgrade.

Comment: How do you get the repositories?